# Before updating Android Studio to 3.0, my Windows computer asks me to give permissions to "JetBrains" updater

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I just tried to update Android Studio to 3.0 and was asked if JetBrains updater could make changes to my device. I've searched online and on here and have not seen much that would associate JetBrains with Android Studio.

Their website, and the JetBrains product seems like a legitimate safe application. The one thing I found was a comment on a blog on the JetBrains website saying

> And as other already said, would be useful to have Android Studio
>   integrated as well. If there are issues with AS using an older
>   platform version then maybe a plugin could help out meanwhile?

Considering that the only thing I found linking it to Android Studio was on **their** website, I'm being cautious. I've never installed JetBrains on my computer. I'm thinking it was either bloatware installed into my new HP computer or it was a recent partnership or something.
Either way, I'm trying to solve this mystery.

Has anyone who has updated had the same phenomenon happen? Is this normal and safe?

EDIT: here's the link to the comment about AS [Link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/25/introducing-jetbrains-toolbox-app/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JetBrains is **legitimate** & **requires permission** whenever you update your Android Studio.

1. **JetBrains** has developed **IntelliJ IDEA Editor**, if you are aware of it, it's a very popular IDE and considered one of the best IDEs for development.
2. If you have ever noticed, when Android Studio starts, it shows something like this: "**Powered by the IntelliJ Platform**", which is ultimately developed by **JetBrains**.

   [image: Android Studio Startup]
3. If you check "About Android Studio" section, it will show something like this: "... **by JetBrains**"

   [image: About Android Studio]

So yes, it is **legitimate** and completely safe to allow and continue setup.

Answer (score 2):

IntelliJ IDE is one of the best Java IDEs and it is developed by [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains) which was formerly called as IntelliJ.

[IntelliJ IDEA is the base for Android Studio](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2013/05/15/intellij-idea-is-the-base-for-android-studio-the-new-ide-for-android-developers/) and Android Studio is based on Community edition of IntelliJ IDE. For more details, visit their [FAQ page](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/).

With no doubt you can  allow JetBrains updater. JetBrains develops best IDEs in market such as IntelliJ, AppCode (for iOS and MacOS), CLion (for C and C++ IDE) and many for various programming languages.

You should allow JetBrains updater whenever a new version of AS is released.